# How to get productlist page view count like product in magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Can I get `product/list.php` view count like `product/view.php` in **magento 1**.

to check how many times list page has been viewed?

Comment: Yes you can. :)

Comment: can you please let me know that how can it be done?

Comment: According to our guidelines: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." 
- No, I cant. What you're looking for can be found by opening google and search for it. Its done in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view count through the `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` model.

```
// set $to and $from to an empty string to disable time range filtering
$from = '2012-01-01';
$to = now();
$productIds = array(9, 35); // your product ids, (works as an int, too) 

$reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $productIds);
```

Each item in the collection is a `catalog/product` instance with a views property set, so you can use `$product->getViews()` to get the count.

If you don't want to load the whole product model and only require the view count, you can get it like this:

```
$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/event');
$select = $resource->getReadConnection()->select()
    ->from(array('ev' => $resource->getMainTable()), array(
        'product_id' => 'object_id',
        'view_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')
    ))
    // join for the event type id of catalog_product_view
    ->join(
        array('et' => $resource->getTable('reports/event_type')),
        "ev.event_type_id=et.event_type_id AND et.event_name='catalog_product_view'",
        ''
    )
    ->group('ev.object_id')

    // add required filters
    ->where('ev.object_id IN(?)', productIds)
    ->where('ev.logged_at >= ?', $from)
    ->where('ev.logged_at <= ?', $to);

$result = $resource->getReadConnection()->fetchPairs($select);
```

This gives you an array, the keys are the product ids and the values are the view counts.